# Permission Denied with running custom script that has correct permissions

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, permissions

I have downloaded script called 'linkhandler' in my /bin/ folder, whose content is below. I have given the file permissions, this is the output from ls -lah:

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 root     861 Jul  8 13:12 linkhandler`

when I run linkhandler in the command line, I get

`/usr/bin/linkhandler: 10: /usr/bin/linkhandler: : Permission denied`

What could be happening? I checked the permissions on the file in the usr folder too.

This is the content of the script, if it helps.

```
  1 #!/bin/sh
  2
  3 # Feed script a url or file location.
  4 # If an image, it will view in sxiv,
  5 # if a video or gif, it will view in mpv
  6 # if a music file or pdf, it will download,
  7 # otherwise it opens link in browser.
  8
  9 # If no url given. Opens browser. For using script as $BROWSER.
 10 [ -z "$1" ] && { "$BROWSER"; exit; }
 11
 12 case "$1" in
 13     *mkv|*webm|*mp4|*youtube.com/watch*|*youtube.com/playlist*|*youtu.be*|*hooktube.com*|*bitchute.com*)
 14         setsid mpv --input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpvsoc$(date +%s) -quiet "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 & ;;
 15     *png|*jpg|*jpe|*jpeg|*gif)
 16         curl -sL "$1" > "/tmp/$(echo "$1" | sed "s/.*\///")" && feh -a "/tmp/$(echo "$1" | sed "s/.*\///")"  >/dev/null 2>&1 & ;;
 17     *mp3|*flac|*opus|*mp3?source*)
 18         setsid tsp curl -LO "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 & ;;
 19     *)
 20         if [ -f "$1" ]; then "$TERMINAL" -e "$EDITOR $1"
 21         else setsid "$BROWSER" "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 & fi ;;
 22 esac
```

Comment: @GAD3R perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/linkhandler: 10: /usr/bin/linkhandler: : Permission denied
```

This is an error message from the shell running the script. It's a bit awkward to read, but there's the `10` which might be a line number, and it's worth noting the weird double colon `: :` before the error message `Permission denied`. It's as if there should be another string before the second colon, but that string is empty.

Your line 10 is

```
[ -z "$1" ] && { "$BROWSER"; exit; }
```

And a potential problem there is that `$BROWSER` might be empty. That still doesn't explain why the name of the script is there again, or if an empty value would cause that error. So let's try to replicate that:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/dash
unset FOO
"$FOO" 
$ ./foo.sh
./foo.sh: 3: ./foo.sh: : Permission denied
```

On Dash, Debian's and Ubuntu's `/bin/sh`, the error message for running a command with an empty message looks quite similar, and indeed the script name is duplicated in the error for some reason. (On Bash, the error message would be different.)

So, it would appear that the problem is indeed in `$BROWSER` being empty. You could check for that with `[ -z "$BROWSER" ]` or supply a default value by using `"${BROWSER-/usr/bin/sensible-browser}"` with an appropriate path.

Comment: Lol im very dumb, thank you